# Is this SQL query equivalent to this relational algebra statement?

Tags: sql, relational-algebra

I have the following SQL query:

```
SELECT foo.a, bar.b, baz.c FROM foo
INNER JOIN bar ON bar.id = foo.bar_id 
INNER JOIN baz ON baz.id = foo.baz_id 
WHERE foo.z = 50;
```

I want to know if this is equivalent to this relational algebra statement.

```
π foo.a, bar.b, baz.c (foo) ⋈ bar.id = foo.bar_id (bar) ⋈ baz.id = foo.baz_id (baz) σ foo.z = 50
```

Comment: Yes, it is. [Here's a set of slides](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/projects/btr/bioinformaticsschool/slides/gehrke.pdf) that you can use to transform your SQL into relational algebra.

Comment: There are many versions of "relational algebra". You are not using project or restrict correctly according to any algebra I've seen. How are project, restrict & join defined in the one that you are supposed to use? Please give a reference for your version. Most presentations of relational algebra have restrict & join that work on *any relation value*. Ie without dot. But dot needs arguments that are either names of relation-valued variables or constants (eg your answer & the accepted answer) or else values plus temporary names (eg SQL).

Comment: Were you given that algebra expression, or did you generate it?

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu Too bad the slides' source textbook has an ideosyncratic needlessly complex algebra involving named relations with ordered columns distinguished by input names. (And "equijoin" that is really natural equijoin.)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, it's (your SQL Query) a representation for your relational statement.

Comment: Take another look at the alleged relatonal algebra expression. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> π foo.a, bar.b, baz.c (foo) ⋈ bar.id = foo.bar_id (bar) ⋈ baz.id = foo.baz_id (baz) σ foo.z = 50
> ```

This algebra expression is not written according to any common version of relational algebra. So we can't say the SQL is equivalent. It seems to be what you have produced rather than what you were given.

Typically we write:

```
π attributes ( relation )
σ condition ( relation )
```

and the algebra expression should be nesting them:

```
π attributes ( σ condition ( relation ) )
```

What conditions you are allowed to write and whether you can use dots with attribute names in any of your operator calls depends on how your algebra is defined. Using dots requires having names accompany relation values passed to operators.

Your question cannot be answered fully until you give a reference to or description of the algebra you are supposed to use.

It seems you might think that all you have to do is replace SELECT by π, JOIN by ⋈ and WHERE by σ. That is wrong.